# pull data from parsed Json with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I want to get my CampaignList from JsonObject which I parsed before. But it gives fatal error while it is running.

Error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
self.CampaignArray = Campaigns as! NSMutableArray
```

The code :

```
var CampaignArray:NSMutableArray = []

func Get(){
    let res: String = ""

    let jsonObject = ["PhoneNumber": "xxxxx"]
    let Jsn = JsonClass(value: jsonObject, text: res)

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://MYURL",parameters: jsonObject,
        encoding: .JSON).validate(statusCode: 200..<303)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            NSLog("response = \(response)")

            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                guard let resultValue = response.result.value else {
                    NSLog("Result value in response is nil")
                    //completionHandler(response: nil)
                    return
                }
                let responseJSON = resultValue
                print(responseJSON)
                let result = Jsn.convertStringToDictionary(responseJSON as! String)!
                print("result: \(result)")
                let Campaigns = (result as NSDictionary)["Campaigns"]
                print(Campaigns)
                self.CampaignArray = Campaigns as! NSMutableArray
                let notifications = (result as NSDictionary)["Notifications"]
                print(notifications)
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                NSLog("Error result: \(error)")
                // Here I call a completionHandler I wrote for the failure case
                return
            }
    }
}
```

And my response Json is:

```
json: {"CampaignList":[
         {"Bonus":"5","CampaignId":"zQUuB2RImUZlcFwt3MjLIA==","City":"34"} 
          {"Bonus":"3","CampaignId":"VgYWLR6eL2mMemFCPkyocA==","City":"34"}],
 "MemberId":"ZBqVhLv\/c2BtMInW52qNLg==",     
 "NotificationList":[{"Notification":"Filiz Makarnadan Milli Piyango Çekiliş Hakkı Kazanmak İster misin ?","PhoneNumber":"555555555"}]}
```

Comment: You should just stop using NSMutableArray/NSDictionary/etc and use Swift arrays and dictionaries. // Do not force unwrap your Optionals, always handle the possible failure with optional binding (if let else). // Also note that variables and properties should be lowercased, otherwise other readers of your code are mislead about the type of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

This library (pod) is very simple and has detailed documentation.

Your example:

I put son file "data.json" in my project and read it. Thank **Daniel Sumara** for your json example correction.

```
  if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            if let CampaignList = json["CampaignList"].array {
                for index in 0 ..< CampaignList.count {

                    print("Campaign [\(index)]")
                    if let CampaignId = CampaignList[index]["CampaignId"].string {
                        print("     CampaignId: \(CampaignId)")
                    }

                    if let City = CampaignList[index]["City"].string {
                        print("     City: \(City)")
                    }

                    if let Bonus = CampaignList[index]["Bonus"].string {
                        print("     Bonus: \(Bonus)")
                    }
                }
            }

            if let MemberId = json["MemberId"].string {
                print("MemberId: \(MemberId)")
            }

            if let NotificationList = json["NotificationList"].array {
                print("NotificationList")
                for notification in NotificationList {
                    if let Notification = notification["Notification"].string {
                         print("     Notification: \(Notification)")
                    }

                    if let PhoneNumber = notification["PhoneNumber"].string {
                        print("     PhoneNumber: \(PhoneNumber)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you can use Alamofire-SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON)

P.S. you have fatal errors because you do not check if value is nil. read about "if let" expression (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: I cant get any result with swifty json. When i print out "json" I can see the output but when i try to print campaigns it return nil.                                                   ' var json = JSON(data)
                print("json: \(json)")
                if let campaigns = json["CampaignList"].array{
                    print("campaigns: \(campaigns)")
                }'

Comment: Could you paste here one of your JSON answers?

Comment: So, this solution helped?

Answer (score 0):

JSON you provide is invalid. There is lack of `,` in Campaigns dictionary. 
Valid JSON looks like:

```
{
  "CampaignList": [
    {
      "Bonus": "5",
      "CampaignId": "zQUuB2RImUZlcFwt3MjLIA==",
      "City": "34"
    },
    {
      "Bonus": "3",
      "CampaignId": "VgYWLR6eL2mMemFCPkyocA==",
      "City": "34"
    }
  ],
  "MemberId": "ZBqVhLv/c2BtMInW52qNLg==",
  "NotificationList": [
    {
      "Notification": "Filiz Makarnadan Milli Piyango Çekiliş Hakkı Kazanmak İster misin ?",
      "PhoneNumber": "555555555"
    }
  ]
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

You receive this error because you try cast nil to `NSDictionary` object. 
You have no `Campaigns` key in JSON you provide, so when you try to get this key from JSON you get nil. In next step you try cast this nil to `NSDictionary`.

Try use `CampaignList` key to get data you want.

```
let result: [String: AnyObject] = Jsn.convertStringToDictionary(responseJSON as! String)!
let campaigns: [Campaign] = result["CampaignList"] as! [Campaign]
print(Campaigns)
self.CampaignArray = campaigns 
let notifications = result["NotificationList"]
print(notifications)
```

The same case will be with your `Notifications` key from JSON Dictionary.

You should also use swift types over objective-c NSDictionary and NSArray.